# Triangle interpolation script not working

Tags: python, interpolation

I solved a part of my question! So I removed the original question and updated it to this one:

I am making a wind interpolation script. There are several weather stations that surround the Wadden Sea. I have done measurements at a certain location (P). And I have a .csv file with all the wind speeds, per station, per time, that looks like this:

```
       STN         DT  HH    FF
0      229   2-1-2021   9  20.0
1      229   2-1-2021  10  20.0
2      229   2-1-2021  11  10.0
3      229   2-1-2021  12  10.0
4      229   2-1-2021  13  30.0
   ...        ...  ..   ...
62747  277  12-3-2022  20  50.0
62748  277  12-3-2022  21  50.0
62749  277  12-3-2022  22  50.0
62750  277  12-3-2022  23  60.0
62751  277  12-3-2022  24  50.0
```

To derive the wind speed at point (P), I will use a triangle interpolation. The script try to fit (P) within a triangle that uses the possible stations as vertices. This works fine now, after some help. I got it in this script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar 16 09:59:31 2022

@author: ###
"""
import itertools
import math
from pyproj import Transformer
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

## data
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\###\\sensoren\\data')
os.getcwd()
wind = pd.read_csv('data_totaal_2.csv', usecols= [ 0, 1,2 , 5],skiprows = 33, names = ['STN','DT','HH','FF'])



## closest point
def min_distance(x, y, iterable):
       list_of_distances = list(map(lambda t: sqrt(pow(t[0]-x,2)+pow(t[1]-y,2)),iterable))
       min_res = min(list_of_distances)
       index_of_min = list_of_distances.index(min_res)
       return iterable[index_of_min]

## check if point is inside triangle
def area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) +
                x2 * (y3 - y1) +
                x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0)


def is_inside(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y):
    A = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A1 = area(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A2 = area(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3)
    A3 = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y)
    return A == A1 + A2 + A3

## calculate perimeter
def perimeter(points):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = *points[0], *points[1], *points[2]
    return (math.hypot(x1-x2, y1-y2) +
            math.hypot(x2-x3, y2-y3) +
            math.hypot(x3-x1, y3-y1))

## barycentric interpolation
def bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inteR_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    W_v1 = ((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v2 = ((inter_cor_y3-inter_cor_y1)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v3 = 1 - W_v1 - W_v2
    inter_wind_pv = (W_v1 * inter_wind_v1) + (W_v2 * inter_wind_v2) +  (W_v3 * inter_wind_v3)
    return inter_wind_pv

       



## datum shift
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:28992")

RD_229 = transformer.transform(53.04309, 4.81969) #texelhors_229
RD_235 = transformer.transform(52.91382, 4.79498) #de_kooy_235
RD_242 = transformer.transform(53.25337, 4.94041) #vlieland_242
RD_251 = transformer.transform(53.39335, 5.34623) #terschelling_251
RD_267 = transformer.transform(52.89709, 5.38331) #stavoren_267
RD_277 = transformer.transform(53.40848, 6.19614) #lauwersoog_277
P =  transformer.transform(53.02, 5.02) #location 1

# =============================================================================
# P =  transformer.transform(50.00, 5.00) #location outside any triangle
# =============================================================================

print(RD_229)
print(RD_235)
print(RD_242)
print(RD_251)
print(RD_267)
print(RD_277)




STN_229_x = RD_229[0]
STN_235_x = RD_235[0]
STN_242_x = RD_242[0]
STN_251_x = RD_251[0]
STN_267_x = RD_267[0]
STN_277_x = RD_277[0]

points = [(RD_229[0],RD_229[1]),(RD_235[0],RD_235[1]),(RD_242[0],RD_242[1]),(RD_251[0],RD_251[1]),(RD_267[0],RD_267[1]),(RD_277[0],RD_277[1])]


## find best triangle or point
triangle_fit = []
for triangle in itertools.combinations(points, 3):
    p1, p2, p3 = triangle
    if is_inside(*p1, *p2, *p3, *P):
       triangle_fit.append(triangle)

triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 


 # Sort by perimeter.

triangle_fit.append(triangle)
triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 
inter_cor = triangle_fit[0]
inter_cor_x1 = inter_cor[0][0]
inter_cor_x2 = inter_cor[1][0]
inter_cor_x3 = inter_cor[2][0]
inter_cor_y1 = inter_cor[0][1]
inter_cor_y2 = inter_cor[1][1]
inter_cor_y3 = inter_cor[2][1]

inter_cor_px = P[0]
inter_cor_py = P[1]


print(inter_cor_x1)
print(inter_cor_x2)
print(inter_cor_x3)
print(inter_cor_y1)
print(inter_cor_y2)
print(inter_cor_y3)

if inter_cor_x1 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v1 = 229
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v1 = 235
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v1 = 242
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v1 = 251
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v1 = 267
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v1 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")

if inter_cor_x2 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v2 = 229
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v2 = 235
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v2 = 242
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v2 = 251
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v2 = 267
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v2 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v2")
    
if inter_cor_x3 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v3 = 229
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v3 = 235
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v3 = 242
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v3 = 251
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v3 = 267
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v3 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")
    

inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1]



inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2]


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3]



df_add = inter_wind_v1.FF.add(inter_wind_v1.FF, fill_value=0)



inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v1:\n{inter_wind_v1}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v2:\n{inter_wind_v2}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v3:\n{inter_wind_v3}")
# =============================================================================

interp = pd.DataFrame(inter_wind_v1['FF']).rename(columns = {'FF':'inter_wind_v1'})
interp['inter_wind_v2'] = inter_wind_v2['FF']
interp['inter_wind_v3'] = inter_wind_v3['FF']
# =============================================================================
# print(interp)
# =============================================================================

def doInterp(inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    return bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3)
interp['inter_wind_pv'] = interp.apply(lambda x: doInterp(x['inter_wind_v1'], x['inter_wind_v2'], x['inter_wind_v3']), axis=1)
print(interp)

filepath = Path('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out.csv')  

filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  

interp.to_csv(filepath)  

os.makedirs('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/', exist_ok=True)  

interp.to_csv('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out2.csv')  

data_s = np.array([
    [RD_229],
    [RD_235],
    [RD_242],
    [RD_251],
    [RD_267],
    [RD_277]
])
data_p = np.array([
    [P]
])


data_i = np.array([
    [ inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_y1],
    [ inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_y2],
    [ inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y3]
])

x_s, y_s = data_s.T
x_p, y_p = data_p. T
x_i, y_i = data_i. T
plt.scatter( x_p, y_p, c="red")
plt.scatter( x_s, y_s, c="blue")
plt.scatter( x_i, y_i, c="green")
plt.show()


## COPY FOR POINT 2 ##

P =  transformer.transform(53.29, 5.40) #location 2


## find best triangle or point
triangle_fit = []
for triangle in itertools.combinations(points, 3):
    p1, p2, p3 = triangle
    if is_inside(*p1, *p2, *p3, *P):
       triangle_fit.append(triangle)

triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 

#sort by perimeter

triangle_fit.append(triangle)
triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 
inter_cor = triangle_fit[0]
inter_cor_x1 = inter_cor[0][0]
inter_cor_x2 = inter_cor[1][0]
inter_cor_x3 = inter_cor[2][0]
inter_cor_y1 = inter_cor[0][1]
inter_cor_y2 = inter_cor[1][1]
inter_cor_y3 = inter_cor[2][1]

inter_cor_px = P[0]
inter_cor_py = P[1]


if inter_cor_x1 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v1 = 229
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v1 = 235
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v1 = 242
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v1 = 251
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v1 = 267
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v1 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")

if inter_cor_x2 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v2 = 229
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v2 = 235
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v2 = 242
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v2 = 251
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v2 = 267
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v2 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v2")
    
if inter_cor_x3 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v3 = 229
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v3 = 235
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v3 = 242
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v3 = 251
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v3 = 267
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v3 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")
    

inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1]



inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2]


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3]



df_add = inter_wind_v1.FF.add(inter_wind_v1.FF, fill_value=0)



inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v1:\n{inter_wind_v1}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v2:\n{inter_wind_v2}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v3:\n{inter_wind_v3}")
# =============================================================================

interp = pd.DataFrame(inter_wind_v1['FF']).rename(columns = {'FF':'inter_wind_v1'})
interp['inter_wind_v2'] = inter_wind_v2['FF']
interp['inter_wind_v3'] = inter_wind_v3['FF']
# =============================================================================
# print(interp)
# =============================================================================

def doInterp(inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    return bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3)
interp['inter_wind_pv'] = interp.apply(lambda x: doInterp(x['inter_wind_v1'], x['inter_wind_v2'], x['inter_wind_v3']), axis=1)
print(interp)

filepath = Path('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out.csv')  

filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  

interp.to_csv(filepath)  

os.makedirs('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/', exist_ok=True)  

interp.to_csv('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out2.csv')  

data_s = np.array([
    [RD_229],
    [RD_235],
    [RD_242],
    [RD_251],
    [RD_267],
    [RD_277]
])
data_p = np.array([
    [P]
    
])


data_i = np.array([
    [ inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_y1],
    [ inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_y2],
    [ inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y3]
])

x_s, y_s = data_s.T
x_p, y_p = data_p. T
x_i, y_i = data_i. T
plt.scatter( x_p, y_p, c="red")
plt.scatter( x_s, y_s, c="blue")
plt.scatter( x_i, y_i, c="green")
plt.show()


## COPY POINT 3 ##

P =  transformer.transform(50.00, 5.00) #location outside any triangle




## find best triangle or point
## find best triangle or point
triangle_fit = []
for triangle in itertools.combinations(points, 3):
    p1, p2, p3 = triangle
    if is_inside(*p1, *p2, *p3, *P):
       triangle_fit.append(triangle)


# best perimeter
triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 

triangle_fit.append(triangle)
triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 
inter_cor = triangle_fit[0]
inter_cor_x1 = inter_cor[0][0]
inter_cor_x2 = inter_cor[1][0]
inter_cor_x3 = inter_cor[2][0]
inter_cor_y1 = inter_cor[0][1]
inter_cor_y2 = inter_cor[1][1]
inter_cor_y3 = inter_cor[2][1]

inter_cor_px = P[0]
inter_cor_py = P[1]


print(inter_cor_x1)
print(inter_cor_x2)
print(inter_cor_x3)
print(inter_cor_y1)
print(inter_cor_y2)
print(inter_cor_y3)

if inter_cor_x1 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v1 = 229
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v1 = 235
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v1 = 242
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v1 = 251
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v1 = 267
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v1 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")

if inter_cor_x2 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v2 = 229
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v2 = 235
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v2 = 242
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v2 = 251
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v2 = 267
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v2 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v2")
    
if inter_cor_x3 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v3 = 229
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v3 = 235
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v3 = 242
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v3 = 251
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v3 = 267
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v3 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")
    

inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1]



inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2]


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3]



df_add = inter_wind_v1.FF.add(inter_wind_v1.FF, fill_value=0)



inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v1:\n{inter_wind_v1}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v2:\n{inter_wind_v2}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v3:\n{inter_wind_v3}")
# =============================================================================

interp = pd.DataFrame(inter_wind_v1['FF']).rename(columns = {'FF':'inter_wind_v1'})
interp['inter_wind_v2'] = inter_wind_v2['FF']
interp['inter_wind_v3'] = inter_wind_v3['FF']
# =============================================================================
# print(interp)
# =============================================================================

def doInterp(inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    return bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3)
interp['inter_wind_pv'] = interp.apply(lambda x: doInterp(x['inter_wind_v1'], x['inter_wind_v2'], x['inter_wind_v3']), axis=1)
print(interp)

filepath = Path('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out.csv')  

filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  

interp.to_csv(filepath)  

os.makedirs('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/', exist_ok=True)  

interp.to_csv('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out2.csv')  

data_s = np.array([
    [RD_229],
    [RD_235],
    [RD_242],
    [RD_251],
    [RD_267],
    [RD_277]
])
data_p = np.array([
    [P]
])


data_i = np.array([
    [ inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_y1],
    [ inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_y2],
    [ inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y3]
])

x_s, y_s = data_s.T
x_p, y_p = data_p. T
x_i, y_i = data_i. T
plt.scatter( x_p, y_p, c="red")
plt.scatter( x_s, y_s, c="blue")
plt.scatter( x_i, y_i, c="green")
plt.show()
```

There are 2 repetitions in this script to see if it works. It creates the following 3 plots:

[plot](https://imgur.com/a/3327YX3)

if blockquote still dont work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gkN4.jpg

And it gives the following dataframe output:

```
2.3863918158
       inter_wind_v1  inter_wind_v2  inter_wind_v3  inter_wind_pv
0               20.0           80.0           30.0      42.620259
1               30.0           60.0           40.0      42.816514
2               20.0           60.0           40.0      39.097197
3               20.0           40.0           40.0      32.561367
4               20.0           50.0           30.0      32.816514
             ...            ...            ...            ...
10459           40.0           80.0           50.0      56.084429
10460           50.0           80.0           50.0      59.803745
10461           50.0           90.0           60.0      66.084429
10462           50.0           80.0           60.0      62.816514
10463           60.0           80.0           60.0      66.535830

[10464 rows x 4 columns]
       inter_wind_v1  inter_wind_v2  inter_wind_v3  inter_wind_pv
0               40.0           30.0           30.0      37.356121
1               30.0           40.0           20.0      31.560683
2               20.0           40.0           30.0      24.746160
3               30.0           40.0           30.0      32.102281
4               20.0           30.0           30.0      22.643879
             ...            ...            ...            ...
10459           50.0           50.0           50.0      50.000000
10460           50.0           50.0           50.0      50.000000
10461           40.0           60.0           50.0      44.746160
10462           60.0           60.0           60.0      60.000000
10463           60.0           60.0           50.0      59.458402

[10464 rows x 4 columns]
152273.8331310129
154737.80483951585
208796.2620382847
600780.6766655241
545552.3863918158
602766.4003272419
       inter_wind_v1  inter_wind_v2  inter_wind_v3  inter_wind_pv
0               40.0           30.0           30.0     -20.684217
1               30.0           40.0           20.0     105.480717
2               20.0           40.0           30.0     148.766684
3               30.0           40.0           30.0      98.082467
4               20.0           30.0           30.0      80.684217
             ...            ...            ...            ...
10459           50.0           50.0           50.0      50.000000
10460           50.0           50.0           50.0      50.000000
10461           40.0           60.0           50.0     168.766684
10462           60.0           60.0           60.0      60.000000
10463           60.0           60.0           50.0      67.398250

[10464 rows x 4 columns]
```

As you can see the 2 scatter plot show the wanted results. The used stations change depending on (P). But when point P is outside of the triangles I would like to not interpolate but take the wind(FF) value of the station closest to point (P) It could be a code that look like this:

```
inter_cor=(min_distance(P[0], P[1], points))
```

But I am not able to implement this. I wonder if somewan knows how I can implement this. And that the dataframe output will be from just one station instead of 3.

I hope somewan can help me with this! I am almost halfway

Comment: Is it possible to plot (a scatter plot for example) the position of P, the 3 stations chosen (in red for ex.)and the others stations (in blue for example) ? Might help to visualize the answer. I suspect that your second position is almost the same as the first position and so it have the same nearest stations.

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
I just learned how to make a scatter plot from the coordinates, thats great.
I cant post this in the comment so I try to edit my original posts

Comment: Thanks, it help a lot. Looking at the plot, it seems there is a problem both in is_inside() and station selection. I can't help more for now but it is interesting. I might look more into it later if it's still unsolved issue

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you had some time later. It seems that Python is selecting the 3 last stations in the list of stations.

Comment: I saw your update, good. Finding the nearest neighbour is not as easy as it could be. If you have only a limited number of station you can calculate the distance (point,station) for all stations. But if you have plenty of stations, you need to do it differently. See Nearest Neigbhour Search problem. It's a bit data dependant, there are different solutions available.

I think you could search for it while doing the triangulation, it would save some time. You actually do it in your perimeter function I think ?